# Internet access for DHCP clients on separate subnet adapter

Tags: routing, bridge

I have a VM (Debian) with two ethernet ports. The `eth0` NIC connects to the broader world and has full Internet access.

```
        192.168.0.3       Static: 10.0.0.1
+-------+  +------------------------+
| world |--| eth0 | computer | eth1 |
+-------+  +------------------------+
```

The `eth1` network device on the same `computer` has a static IP. `dnsmasq` runs using that `eth1` interface. It handles DHCP and DNS and downstream clients are able to connect and get IP addresses.

```
    DHCP: 192.168.0.3       Static: 10.0.0.1
+-------+  +------------------------+
| world |--| eth0 | computer | eth1 |
+-------+  +------------------------+        DHCP: 10.0.0.x
                                |             +--------+   
                                +-------------|client 1|   
                                |             +--------+   
                                |             +--------+   
                                +-------------|client 2|   
                                              +--------+
```

This all works as expected *except* that `client 1` and `client 2` cannot access the Internet. They can `ssh` and `ping` `10.0.0.1`, but nothing upstream from that. They cannot ping `192.168.0.3`, `1.1.1.1`, `google.com`, etc.

How do I maintain this configuration but allow the `10.0.0.x` clients to connect to the Internet?

I've tried...

- Various ways of [adding routes](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-configuring-default-route-with-ipcommand/) to interfaces

  - e.g. `ip route add 192.168.0.3 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1`
- Creating a [network bridge](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge) with both interfaces

  - e.g. `ip link add name br0 type bridge ; ip link set eth0 up ; ip link set eth1 up ; ip link set eth0 master br0 ; ip link set eth1 master br0 ; ip link set br0 up`
- Using `iptables` to route traffic

  - e.g. `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE`

Unfortunately, nothing has worked. Probably because I don't understand the mechanics of these commands and configurations and basic networking limitations well enough.

Comment: You need to set `ip_forward` on the computer.

Comment: I was thinking the same. It looks like it's already enabled though `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` yields `1`

Comment: The FORWARD chain may block traffic. In principle, if no traffic is filtered, it is sufficient for the `computer` to have a route to the destination address through the other NIC and to enable `ip_forward`. In your case, I suspect netfilter rules that block traffic or process it incorrectly. For testing, I'd remove all rules (including `nat` and other tables if appropriate), then recreate those that are really required to secure the `computer`.

Comment: By the way, do clients have a route to the internet through `computer`? `ip r get 1.1.1.1` on the clients to confirm.

Comment: `ip r get 1.1.1.1` on `computer` looks reasonable. It shows a route to `192.168.0.1` (the upstream gateway). The DHCP clients show a route to `10.0.0.1` as their default. I see a `-P FORWARD DROP` rule on `computer`. If I change it to `ACCEPT` I still have no luck. I realized I lied though. I _can_ ping `192.168.0.3` (`computer`) from the DHCP clients.

Comment: To summarize: `computer` can access `world`. Clients can access `computer`'s world-facing IP address, but not `world`. The network is connected to `world` via a router at 192.168.0.1. Correct? If so, my questions are: Can clients access 192.168.0.1? If yes, what default route is configured on the clients? Or: Just add clients' routing table to the question.

Comment: You've got it all correct! Clients _cannot_ access `192.168.0.1`.

I added these iptables commands and things seem to be working now. I have to admit I was just throwing commands at the wall and I'm not sure why this did it. `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --src 10.0.0.0/24 --dst 0/0 -j ACCEPT && iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE && iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

Comment: In hindsight that's probably because your "world router" doesn't have a route to 10.0.0.0/24 (also: schematic is incomplete, route command in OP looks bogus and nat/PREROUTING rule in comment is useless)